# Where should I put common logic for creating an object?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

So, we have a class **RestSearchCriteria** which can be serialized to JSON and it is used to query all of our APIs.

Let's say I want to search only in **active** articles, so we have to check the state, publish_from and publish_to fields. Also, limit and offset criteria parameters should be handled based on the provided PaginationConfig class, etc. It's quite a lot of logic which is used in many places in the code.

Where should we put this logic? We did some research about Factory and Builder patterns but aren't quite sure how to implement those.

Our current solution looks something like that:

```php
public function findActiveArticles(
    RestSearchCriteria $criteria,
    PaginationConfig $paginationConfig
): ArticlesResult {
    // mutate the criteria object by adding parameters for article state, publish_from, publish_to
    // mutate the criteria object by setting limit and skip parameters based on the pagination config

    // fetch and return data using criteria
}
```

This way, code is duplicated in many places and criteria object is mutated, which is very hard to test. What we want is to get rid of these methods and replace them with one **findArticles($criteria)** method and move this logic for preparing the criteria somewhere else.

Comment: define a default Criteria what ever that is and save it somewhere, now create a resetCriteria function that contains all your logic for getting search results based on different criteria, this function takes in one argument which by default is null, let's say if criteria is null you call the default Criteria otherwise you call the criteria that was passed as argument. and use this one function for all your search APIs

Comment: @Snipo *"This way, code is duplicated in many places"*. Can you show code examples that demonstrates code duplication to understand what exact duplication are you trying to eliminate? Also, you say that *It's quite a lot of logic*, can you show a code example of what you mean by this and why it is a candidate for reusability?

Comment: @CKing For active articles, it's a setting combination of parameters to query only active articles. This combination is business logic and can change. For pagination calculating limit and skip criteria from page and itemsPerPage params. Currently **each search method in all services is applying it** using helper methods. We want to move this logic to criteria creation process and not mutate the existing query in service methods.